# FWRITE() Saving file to a specific location

Tags: php, fwrite, mkdir

This code below is using the FWRITE function. however i wish to save the file to a specific location but always get 'cant open file' as expected. i have setup the directory listed in mypath but it still wont write to that location.

```
   $mypath = "http://www.mysite.com/test/data/";
    $myFile = $mypath."data.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "Some text";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [HTTP wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) does not support writing.  If mysite.com is the same server you're running on, and that's a physical directory, you would use a regular file path (no HTTP).  What filename that URL corresponds to depends entirely on how your server is set up.

If it's a different machine, you need to use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or another solution to do a PUT or POST.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a logical path to save the file such as:

/home/mysitefolder/public_html/test/data/

also check to make sure that PHP is running as Apache and has permissions to write to that folder.

Answer (score -1):

Your path is wrong; you can't use `http://` as a path, you need something like `/var/www/test/data` as `$mypath`.